# Python Selenium - move vue slider on exchange

Tags: python, selenium, vue.js, vue-component

Im working on a crypto trading system, I don't have an access to the exchange API at the moment so I decided to try the solution using Selenium automation.
What I cannot figure out is how to move vue slider in exchange (to set a buying amount to 100%).

This is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import io
import subprocess

#proc = subprocess.Popen("./ChannelMessages.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
executor_url = driver.command_executor._url
session_id = driver.session_id

print(session_id)
print(executor_url)

driver.get("https://www.hotbit.io/exchange?symbol=XRP_USDT")

time.sleep(10)
en =  driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/ul/li/form[1]/section[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]')
move = ActionChains(driver)
move.click_and_hold(en).move_by_offset(50, 0).release().perform()
```

This is a slider code:

```
<div data-v-33e6e6c8="" class="percent-box"><div class="vue-slider vue-slider-ltr v-left-slider" style="padding: 7px 0px; width: auto; height: 4px;"><div class="vue-slider-rail"><div class="vue-slider-process" style="height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0%; width: 0%; transition-property: width, left; transition-duration: 0.5s;"></div><div class="vue-slider-marks"><div class="vue-slider-mark vue-slider-mark-active" style="height: 100%; width: 4px; left: 0%;"><div class="vue-slider-mark-step vue-slider-mark-step-active"></div></div><div class="vue-slider-mark" style="height: 100%; width: 4px; left: 25%;"><div class="vue-slider-mark-step"></div></div><div class="vue-slider-mark" style="height: 100%; width: 4px; left: 50%;"><div class="vue-slider-mark-step"></div></div><div class="vue-slider-mark" style="height: 100%; width: 4px; left: 75%;"><div class="vue-slider-mark-step"></div></div><div class="vue-slider-mark" style="height: 100%; width: 4px; left: 100%;"><div class="vue-slider-mark-step"></div></div></div><div aria-valuetext="0%" class="vue-slider-dot vue-slider-dot-hover" role="slider" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-orientation="horizontal" tabindex="0" style="width: 14px; height: 14px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); top: 50%; left: 0%; transition: left 0.5s ease 0s;"><div class="vue-slider-dot-handle"></div><div class="vue-slider-dot-tooltip vue-slider-dot-tooltip-top"><div class="vue-slider-dot-tooltip-inner vue-slider-dot-tooltip-inner-top"><span class="vue-slider-dot-tooltip-text">0%</span></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Maybe I'm looking for the wrong element in "driver.find_element", tried different elements thought, not sure.

P.S. I tried to locate elements using "name" and "xpath", tried basically all levels of classes to use, but still I couldn't move it, or even select it.

Any help will be much appreciated!

P.P.S: Resolved!
Needed to add a line:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

and to modify `"driver.find_element"` line:

```
en = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'v-left-slider')
```

Comment: I suggest you to try `pyautogui`, it always work but is less precise because you cannot drag an object from one element to another, but rather from one position to another based on the cursor's coordinates

Comment: What happens if you run the code? Does nothing happen or does it show you an error?

Comment: @soundwave thank you for your suggestion! I will try to use pyatogui, didn't new about it.

Comment: @RomanJ Nothing happens, it seems I'm entering wrong element in "driver.find_element", I tried to locate elements using "name" and "xpath", tried basically all levels of classes to use, but still I couldn't move it, or even select it.

Comment: `move_by_offset` not always work, don't know why 

Comment: I actually found a solution,
added a line: 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
and modified "driver.find_element" line:
en =  driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'v-left-slider')
Now it works!
Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add a line:

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
and to modify "driver.find_element" line:

en = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'v-left-slider')